# Passing JSON to Node.JS using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, serialization

I'm trying to pass the following to my node.js server:

```
{
    "SKU": {
    "comment": {
        "name": "23",
        "com": "32"
        }
    }
}
```

This is to be stored in a text file. The SKU, name, and com are all variable.

This will be given to the server via an AJAX get command. I've tried serializing form data, but I can't figure out how to get any children in that way (Everything ends up on the same line, like this:

```
{'SKU':'','COMMENT':'','NAME':'23','COM':'32'}
```

I've also tried marking up the data as JSON, like so:

```
var data2 = '{"' + doit + '":{"comment":{"name":"' + name + '","com":"' + com + '"}}}'
```

but what I get is:

```
{ '{"GS-70":{"comment":{"name":"23","com":"32"}}}': '' }
```

Which isn't really what I want.

What is the correct way to pass this data?

Edit for more data:

Code being sent to the server via the following AJAX command:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://localhost:55555",
  data: data2,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify()`.... never invent your own mechanism for building JSON or you run into problems like this.

Comment: What exactly do I stringify to get the results that I want?

Comment: @SeanDenny The object that you want.  I'm not really sure how else to answer your question.